# Short story about aliens who use terrifying dreams/visions to conquer other species

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, alien-invasion, telepathy

I read this story many years ago so I've forgotten most of the details.  I think it was told from the point of view of a narrator going through the experience.

People all over the world began having terrifying dreams and/or visions about some impending disaster.  (I think it was an alien invasion, but it might have been some other sort of calamity.)  All the people of Earth were going to suffer horribly before being wiped out.  Everyone became convinced that it was really going to happen and that it could not be avoided.  So the whole world collectively decided to commit suicide to avoid the suffering.  I believe they planned first to painlessly euthanize all the children, and then the adults would kill themselves.

It was revealed (too late) at the end of the story that there really was an alien invasion, but the aliens had only one weapon: the ability to telepathically project images of suffering and death into the minds of other species in order to frighten them into destroying themselves.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, did you read it in an anthology, a magazine, or online?

Comment: It's been so long that I'm mostly just guessing; but there's a good chance it was in a magazine around 1983-84.  I was in grad school then and sometimes read various then-current sci-fi magazines in the university library reading room.  I tend to re-read anthologies and I'm pretty certain I never read this story more than once, so the magazines at the library would be a good guess.